# What's the typesafe way to write a type guard for a union of types that don't have anything in common?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with PouchDB, which returns an array of possibly mixed success responses or errors on bulk operations.

The success response should always have a field `ok` set to `true` in it, while an error response may have a bunch of all optional fields.

I want to filter out all errors from this, but can't figure out a sane type guard that would narrow this for me.

The straightforward approach would be:

```
interface PouchResponse {
    ok: boolean;
}

interface PouchError {
    status?: number;
    reason?: string;
}

function isError(
    respOrError:
        | PouchResponse
        | PouchError)
    : respOrError is PouchError {
    return !respOrError.ok;
}
```

But that breaks on `ok` not existing in `PouchResponse | PouchError`. Which does make sense given how type intersections work, but my intent here is to check that the property exists and is `true` if it does.

I could change the signature to:

```
function isError(respOrError: Partial<PouchResponse & PouchError>): respOrError is PouchError
```

but that doesn't quite feel right, because it doesn't really reflect what the function is supposed to do: tell apart a union. It shouldn't be possible to pass any other random object into this function and have it narrow said object to `PouchError` just because it doesn't have an `ok` property.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, as I was rubberducking this here I remembered the trick to use; I can just widen the type inside the function to keep the signature the way I want it:

```
function isError(respOrError: PouchResponse | PouchError): respOrError is PouchError {
    const wide: Partial<PouchResponse & PouchError> = respOrError;
    return !wide.ok;
}
```

Comment: I would normally just cast it to `any` in these cases because I know exactly what I'm looking for. Using `Partial<A & B>` is a cleaner way. :)